# DOS batch process to move files to relevant folders

Tags: batch-file, dos

I want to write a DOS batch process which will go through my Directory and move all *.txt files to a dest folder to starting with the first character of the txt files

Ex.
abc.txt will move to folder "a"
def.txt will move to folder "d"
and so on...

Comment: For clarification, do you mean a batch file for use in pure DOS, or in the command prompt under windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line:

```
for %i in (*.txt) do (set FOLDER=%i & move %i %FOLDER:~0,1%)
```

In a batch file, you would have to double the %'s, like this:

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do (set FOLDER=%%i & move %%i %FOLDER:~0,1%)
```

Comment: Adding **& if not exist %FOLDER:~0,1% md %FOLDER:~0,1%** right before the **move** word is crucial, it will otherwise move files to a file named "a", "b", and so on... But it works. Also finish the move command with a backslash in the path, like ** %FOLDER:~0,1%\ ** to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point of the problem is to extract the first letter.

you can use the ~ char to extract the first letter of the file name

```
set str=filename
echo %str:~0,1%
f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the biterscripting **chex command (character extractor)** to extract the first character of the file name. Here is the script. Assume your files are at C:\My Directory.

```
# Script move1.txt
# Change directory to My Directory.
cd "C:\My Directory"

# Collect a list of *.txt files.
var str list ; lf -n "*.txt" > $list

# Go thru files one by one.
while ($list <> "")
do

    # Get the next file.
    var str file ; lex "1" $list > $file

    # $file now has full path of a found *.txt file. Get just the file name.
    var str filename ; stex -p "^/^l[" $file > $filename

    # $filename has just the file name. Get the first character.
    var str firstchar ; chex -p "1" $filename > $firstchar

    # $firstchar now has the first char of file name. The folder where we
    # want to move this file is, then, C:\Destimation Folder\$firstchar .
    var str destfolder ; set $destfolder = "C:\Destination Folder\"+$firstchar

    # Move $file to $destfolder.
    system move ("\""+$file+"\"") ("\""+$destfolder+"\"")

done
```

Script is in biterscripting ( http://www.biterscripting.com ) . To try, save the script as C:\Scripts\move1.txt, start biterscripting, enter the following command.

```
script move1.txt
```

If you need to run the script periodically, schedule the following command in the task scheduler.

```
"C:\biterScripting\biterScripting.exe" "move1.txt"
```

I have not tested the script, test it on sample files. **Make sure you change the "C:\My Directory" and "C:\Destination Folder" to their correct values. Always use double quotes with file names and paths.**

Answer (score 0):

How about this is one line:

the general form:
for %a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do if not exist %a\nul md %a & if exist %a* move %a* %a

this mod will do just the txt files (per the OP):
   ... if exist %a*.txt move %a*.txt %a

or one could enhance this in a bat to do "...if exist %%a*%1 move %%a*%1 %%a" to allow extension matching on the commandline; which would probably require the dot in %1 (don't feel like testing that right now.  If this was a problem, you could always have an if%1!==! to choose between the general form and a %1-specific with the dot already provided.

of course, %a is for the commandline and for a bat, double up the %s as normal (%a -> %%a).

this solution will avoid errors with spaces in filenames but you will end up with a subdir for every letter (even if there were no files beginning with that particular letter).

and it's now taken me longer to type this in than to type up the original line above...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Count all TSV files in current folder.

```
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir *.tsv /b') do (
echo %%~nf
findstr /R /N "^" %%f | find /C ":"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
copy sourcepath\a*.txt destinationpath\a
```

copy sourcepath\b*.txt destinationpath\b

Comment: I need an automated script which goes through the directory and does this exact thing by itself :)

Comment: Not to mention that would be to copy, not move